# Arguments from Glob (with spaces)

Tags: bash, arguments

Continuing my fight with arguments and spaces, consider a directory with 3 other
directories and a script:

```
Folder One
Folder Two
Folder Three
script
```

And script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $@
do
    echo $i
done
```

When running it as:

```
./script *
```

I get this output:

```
Folder
One
Folder
Two
Folder
Three
script
```

Is there some way to get this output:

```
Folder One
Folder Two
Folder Three
script
```

In other words, not to split the arguments `$@` on spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask you why it works but `man bash` explains it in detail.